# Strange error You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql

Im tring save a form data to a table, but it getting mysql error, i checked everywhwre data types and all other things are ok, here is my mysql query

```
 INSERT INTO personal_events
        VALUES (
        evt_date, evt_start, evt_end, evt_subject, evt_notes, evt_user
        )
        VALUES (
        '2013-03-29', '11', '12', 'test', 'test notess', 21
       )
```

error details

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES( '2013-03-29', '11', '12', 'test', 'test notess', 21)' at line 1
```

can anyone help me to fix this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two `VALUES`. Use the following:

```
INSERT INTO personal_events
    (
    evt_date, evt_start, evt_end, evt_subject, evt_notes, evt_user
    )
    VALUES (
    '2013-03-29', '11', '12', 'test', 'test notess', 21
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the format

```
INSERT INTO personal_events (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (data1, data2, data3, data4)
```

The columns map to your database columns, the datas are the data you insert. Your statement contains  2 values, hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 INSERT INTO personal_events
    (
    evt_date, evt_start, evt_end, evt_subject, evt_notes, evt_user
    )
    VALUES (
    '2013-03-29', '11', '12', 'test', 'test notess', 21
   )
```

This is your solution